# Access Delete Command Issue

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am still working away on this form and now I am ecountering an error with the delete code portion. I believe it is having a problem recognizing what I am selecting but I could be wrong. The error message reads RUN TIME ERROR 3265 ITEM NOT FOUND IN THIS COLLECTION

The whole code reads:

```
Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
'delete record
'check existing selected record
If Not (Me.TableSub.Form.Recordset.EOF And Me.TableSub.Form.Recordset.BOF) Then
    'confirm delete
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this record?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    'delete now
    CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM KWTable WHERE text_key='" &     Me.TableSub.Form.Recordset.Fields    ("text_key") & "'"
        'refresh data in list
        Me.TableSub.Form.Requery
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

And the portion that is highlighted is:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM KWTable WHERE text_key='" & Me.TableSub.Form.Recordset.Fields    ("text_key") & "'"
```

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates the subform's `Recordset` does not include a field named *text_key*.

In detail, you are getting error #3265, *"Item not found in this collection."*   The only place in the code which could trigger that error is `Me.TableSub.Form.Recordset.Fields("text_key")`. You know `Me.TableSub.Form.Recordset` is valid, because if it weren't then you would have gotten an error earlier (on `If Not (Me.TableSub.Form.Recordset ...`).  That means the recordset's `Fields` collection does not include an `Item` named *"text_key"*.

If you revise the code as @JohnnyBones suggested, you will continue to get the same error, but the error will then be triggered at the `"MySQLString = ..."` line instead of the `CurrentDb.Execute` line.

When you get that error message, click the Debug button, and use this in the Immediate window to list the names of the fields in that `Recordset`.

```vb
for each f in Me.TableSub.Form.Recordset.Fields: _
? f.Name : _
next
```

Note the `_` line continuation characters.  You must use at least 1 space before and 0 spaces after each `_`

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that your problem lies here:

```
Me.TableSub.Form.Recordset.Fields    ("text_key")
```

Try doing this:

```
MySQLString = "DELETE FROM KWTable WHERE text_key='" &     Me.TableSub.Form.Recordset.Fields    ("text_key") & "'"
CurrentDb.Execute MySQLString
```

I have a feeling that when you break the code, your MySQLString variable isn't going to be equal to what you think it is.  And I'm pretty sure that's because of the double-quotes around the field name, unless I'm misunderstanding your error.

Comment: I tried switching in your code and I continue to get the same error.